# Do 2nd Peter 3:12 and Amos 5:18 contradict each other in their advice in regard to the day of God?

Tags: contradiction, 2-peter, amos

Amos and 2nd Peter seem like they might be giving contradictory messages. In Peter, readers are instructed to "expect and hasten" the day of God, while Amos discourages "craving after" the day.

#### 2 Peter 3:12

- προσδοκώντας και σπευδοντας
  expecting and hastening
- την παρουσιαν
  the becoming present
- της του θεου ημερας
  of the day of god

#### Amos 5:18

- הוי
  Darn!
- המתאוים
  those who crave
- את יום יי
  for the day of the LORD
- למה זה לכם יום יי
  what is to them day of the LORD
- הוא חשך ולא אור
  it is darkness and not light

Does instruction to "expect and hasten the day" contradict the discouragement from "craving after the day"? Please explain why or why not. Is there a justifiable explanation for the two contexts in which these verses don't contradict each other?

Theory A:

Majority of bible-observant Christian theology holds that 2 Peter 3:12 encourages a believer to behave in a way to *expect* and that would *hasten* coming of "the day".

Fact B:

Amos 5:18 disdains those who crave after "the day".

Theory C:

The "day" of 2Peter 3:12 is referring to the "day" of Amos 5:18.

Therefore,

1. Do you agree with the confluence of Theory A, Fact B and Theory C?
2. If you do, then 2Peter 3:12 contradicts Amos 5:18. And you need to address that contradiction. Otherwise explain how there is not any contradiction.
3. If you don't agree there is insufficient confluence of Theory A, Fact B and Theory C, then explain your position.

#### Adding a few more details, 2019-06-16

- I found out that now that there is no single view on "the day of LORD"
- those who say there are two days of the LORD are not the majority

Many hold that the term "day of the LORD" is simply generic for the many occurrences "of the LORD". Therefore the contradiction still stands:

If Amos is describing any generic "day of the LORD" and that no one should CRAVE for any day of the LORD - why then is 2 Peter CRAVING for the "day of the LORD" ?

Comment: του θεου is either "the god" or "God," but not simply the anarthrous and miniscular "god."

Comment: This question could use a little more explanation. What exactly (in prose) do you think the contradiction would be here?

Comment: Why would anyone vote the question down? Is the question not legit? Does the question offend anyone ?

Comment: It's not illegitimate or offensive; it's unclear.

Comment: @BlessedGeek It's not only opaque - anyone who takes the trouble to set the two texts in context will see that there is no contradiction. If you perceive a contradiction that I'm failing to spot, *that* needs to go in your question. You need to help potential answerers see the problem you see. Thus my DV. Hope that helps!

Comment: So now I have edited my question to make it clearer ?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, it's a perfectly valid question. I'm aware I don't understand or read things the same as everyone else but to me this is even more clear than prose. Perhaps the issue is you are making a presumption first and basing your question on that instead of questioning the initial theory first.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I think you need to ask this question with a neutral tone instead of asserting that B is a fact. The question is valid but the way it is being asked is not proper.

Comment: Though I provided an answer, I down voted this question due to lack of the most basic of research: reading the surrounding verses. This question would not have been asked if you would have done so.

Comment: I have dedicated my life to proving the Christian scriptures are in extreme disagreement to the original Hebrew of the Bible (and in so doing proving that Jesus is a pagan god). And so far, I have been successful with no Christian ever able to respond against my proofs. All ya'll have been able to do is delete or flag my comments in forums. And now you want me to research your Christian literature that I have been successfully working hard to disprove?

Comment: Kusno, the question is in neutral tone. When you are biased to your side, the principle of relativity says that you would perceive the median as biased against you.

Answer (score 3):

With questions like this it is always better to compare the NT with LXX, where you are at least dealing with the same language. The LXX of the Amos passage reads:

οὐαὶ οἱ ἐπιθυμοῦντες τὴν ἡμέραν κυρίου

As you can see, the verb is different in the two passages. If the author of 2 Peter had intended to contradict Amos one would have expected him to mirror the language of the latter a bit more closely.

Comment: LXX is not the original Hebrew.

Comment: No, but it is version used by all the authors of the NT.

Comment: Which means Jesus in Christian theology was not intended fulfill the scrutiny of the original Hebrew scriptures?

Answer (score 2):

No Peter does not contradict Amos

2 Peter 3:10-12 "But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night, in which the heavens will pass away with a great noise, and the elements will melt with fervent heat; both the earth and the works that are in it will be burned up. Therefore, since all these things will be dissolved, **what manner of persons ought you to be** in holy conduct and godliness, looking for and hastening the coming of the day of God, because of which the heavens will be dissolved, being on fire, and the elements will melt with fervent heat?"

Here the writer is saying what he wants his readers to be like. One of the things he desires for them is to be the sort of people who are longing for the return of the Lord.

However in Amos 5:18 the context is entirely different. Amos 5:1 "Hear this word which I take up against you, a lamentation, O house of Israel:" Here the writer is not encouraging but lamenting. He is not exhorting but rebuking. The people he is addressing will not fair well in the judgement so they should not be looking forward to it.

What is interesting is that the ones that Peter addresses don'e seem to be anticipating the judgement despite the fact that they will be safe in it, but the ones in danger seem eager for the judgement - but that is probably another question.

Comment: I don't understand the word "context" you used here. Are you saying the two "day"s are not the same "day" ? The core of the matter is "are they contradicting instructions" ?

Comment: No I am not say they are different 'days' both are a reference to the day of judgement but the context of the individual references is different! Amos is speaking to people who are under the risk of judgement whereas Peter is speaking to people who are safe from judgement therefore what they say about the relevance of that day is different for their respective audiences

Comment: So is it good to crave, expect and hasten the "day"? Or is it bad? So, Amos is not applicable to Christians?

Comment: So when there is rebuke, it is only meant for Jews and Israel. When it is good, like the new covenant addressed to Israel and Jews in Jer 31:31, then you cherry-pick to say it includes Christians?

Comment: Not at all, I merely let the context derive if the reference to the day of judgement is being used positively or negatively. Your question was in relation to two specific texts which I addressed. If you wish to widen the question then we could look at how the day of judgement is used positively in relation to Israel (the Old Testament Church) and negatively for the New Testament Church - but that wasn't the question as I understood it.

Comment: So, 2Pet3:12 does not say any believer/devotee should expect and hasten *the day*? Only certain people are to expect and hasten *the day*? Are you saying that not everyone should expect and hasten *the day*?

Comment: Scriptural machiavellianism = the strategy of maintaining more than one context and meaning for a concept, such that the meaning is conveniently switched at all costs to ensure the integrity of a doctrine, without consideration to the integrity of the concept itself.

Comment: Finally, I only read the Hebrew - I did not realise the English translations are saying it another way. Sorry I refuse to read the English translations of the Hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

No,  do not think that there is a contradiction because these passages are not speaking of the same day historically or allegorically.
Amos was speaking specifically to the house of Israel, the house of Joseph,  the northern kingdom of the ten tribes if Israel. (Amos 5) He was writing before their captivity by the Assyrians.
Israel's "day" of judgment was yet to come due to their wickedness. (Amos 1:1). Their day would be dark indeed and it was prophecied early in their kingdom's history. Like a dark cloud hanging over them they knew it was coming eventually and they did not want it to come soon. 
Contrast that to Peter encouraging holiness and preparing for the day when the wicked world is judged and a new and righteous heaven and earth become their home. (2 Peter 3:13).
Christians were getting impatient for the day they were also promised,  like Israel,  but they feared its delay instead.
They are different days historically and chronologically and also in tone and target. I say different but you could also see them as mirror images, a reverse parallel. 
Amos wrote to those who should fear judgment while Peter wrote to those who should welcome it with faith.

Answer (score 0):

### Amos

> 12 For I know your manifold transgressions
>   And your mighty sins:
>   Afflicting the just and taking bribes;
>   Diverting the poor from justice at the gate.
>   13 Therefore the prudent keep silent at that time,
>   For it is an evil time.
>   [-Amos 5:12-13 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Amos+5%3A12-13&version=NKJV)

Amos is addressing the wicked, those who's sins are mighty and have manifold transgressions. They are taking bribes and depriving the poor of justice.

> 14 Seek good and not evil,
>   That you may live;
>   So the Lord God of hosts will be with you,
>   As you have spoken.
>   Hate evil, love good;
>   Establish justice in the gate.
>   It may be that thte Lord God of hosts
>   Will be gracious to the remnant of Joseph.
>   [-Amos 5:14-15 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Amos+5%3A14-15&version=NKJV)

The admonishment is to seek good and not evil, because the problem is that they are *not* seeking good and instead seeking evil.

> 21 “I hate, I despise your feast days,
>   And I do not savor your sacred assemblies.
>   22 Though you offer Me burnt offerings and your grain offerings,
>   I will not accept them,
>   Nor will I regard your fattened peace offerings.
>   23 Take away from Me the noise of your songs,
>   For I will not hear the melody of your stringed instruments.
>   24 But let justice run down like water,
>   And righteousness like a mighty stream.”
>   [-Amos 5:21-24 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Amos+5%3A21-24&version=NKJV)

God hates their sacred assemblies and will not accept their sacrifices because they are *not* letting justice run down like water. They are offering sacrifices as if they were righteous, but they are not. They think that since they are keeping the feasts days, holding sacred assemblies, and offering burnt offerings and songs, that they have nothing to fear on the day of the Lord. But God says that they should not look forward to it, since it will be darkness to them because they love evil and will be destroyed.

### Peter

> 10 But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night, in which the heavens will pass away with a great noise, and the elements will melt with fervent heat; **both the earth and the works that are in it will be burned up**. 11 Therefore, since all these things will be dissolved, **what manner of persons ought you to be in holy conduct and godliness**, 12 looking for and hastening the coming of the day of God, because of which the heavens will be dissolved, being on fire, and the elements will melt with fervent heat? 13 Nevertheless we, according to His promise, look for new heavens and a new earth in which righteousness dwells.
>   [-2 Peter 3:10-13 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Peter+3%3A10-13&version=NKJV)

Peter is speaking to the righteous, telling them that they should look for and hasten the day of the Lord, yet warning them that if they do not remain in "holy conduct and godliness" they will be burned up on that day.

> Therefore, beloved, looking forward to these things, be diligent to be found by Him in peace, without spot and blameless;
>   [-2 Peter 3:14 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Peter+3%3A14&version=NKJV)

The righteous should look forward to the day of the Lord, since it will truly be a day of peace for them. But here again is another warning that not one spot will be allowed for anyone on that day. The righteous must not cherish even a small sin, for they will then not be found "blameless" and be burned up along with the earth and everything in it.

### Conclusion

- Amos discourages the wicked from desiring the day of the Lord, since they will be destroyed due to their love of evil. The only way they will live is  if they seek good instead of evil.
- Peter encourages the righteous to look for and hasten the day of the Lord, since He will then provide for them "new heavens and a new earth in which righteousness dwells." They should look forward to these things, and be diligent to remain without spot and blameless.

Comment: So the {מתאוים} in Amos 5, only applies to the wicked (and to the antisemitic, only to wicked Israel)? Therefore, since you narrowed the scope of a generic statement, will you also narrow the scope of Amos 5:24? {ויגל כמים משפט וצדקה כנחל איתן then shall roll as water justice and righteousness as mighty stream} - So this verse can only be quoted to Jews/Israel, any you cannot use this verse on any other than Jews? Are you saying that????

Comment: I mean, make up your mind. Are you inventing a principle, and then backpedaling on it a few verses later?

Comment: @CynthiaAvishegnath (formerly BlessedGeek) - I'm not sure what you're getting at. Nowhere did I say or imply that these verses in Amos apply to Jews/Israel only. While yes, the Lord is speaking to the house Israel (Amos 5:1, 4), anyone, whether Jew or Gentile, who loves evil instead of good, accepts bribes, deprives the poor of justice, etc, should not look forward to the day of the Lord. It will be darkness to them since they will be destroyed on that day.

Comment: Prophecy tends to be dual in application and fulfillment.  Not always, but often enough.  This could apply to the self righteous Jews back then, but also to self righteous Christians in the end time.  Generally speaking, people who are earnestly desiring the Day of the Lord are those who think they've got all their ducks in a row.  People who are more aware of their shortcomings are a bit more cautious.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

There are 2 different “days” being spoken of : the Day of the Lord and the Day of God.

The Day of the Lord spoken of in 2 Peter 3:10 is the Day of Judgment for those who are still under His wrath that rises upon all people for ungodliness and unrighteousness while the Day of God speaks of the Day of His rest for those who serve Him (in all holy behavior and godliness) and have labored to be entered into it.

The presence (parousia) of the  Day of God is to be greatly anticipated by us and hurried as we strive to enter into His rest and out from under His wrath as the current heavens and earth are stored with fire now for our destruction (for ungodliness and unrighteousness of men).   His wrath IS REVEALED from Heaven upon all.

The current system (the old things that are now:  death, sorrow, pain under His arising wrath) are to be changed for those who enter into His rest (in this earth) as the heavens now that have stored fire for our destruction are dissolved so that they cannot destroy our mortal bodies as we shall not be any longer under His wrath but have entered into His rest.

The current heavens being on fire for our destruction are to be dissolved for us in this earth. His wrath is to be dissolved over us as we are to strive and enter into His rest…under His shadow where there will be no longer the sun of His wrath lighting upon our mortal bodies. They shall hunger no more, neither thirst any more; **neither shall the sun light on them, nor any heat.**

The “elements” burning are to be decomposed as they have no more power to destroy us from this earth.

> 2 Peter 3:12 KJV (12)  *L**ooking for and hasting unto the coming of the
>   day of God, wherein the heavens being on fire shall be dissolved, and
>   the elements shall melt with fervent heat**?*

How do we hasten unto the coming of the Day of God?

By being people behaving in all holy behavior and godliness…serving Him always.

We depart from being under His wrath that arises upon all people and enter into His rest in this earth.  We do not leave this earth but instead the wrath of God dissipates/dissolves from our lives so that we may live here without death nor sorrow nor pain nor crying here in this earth.  Instead of the sun of His wrath arising upon us for destruction, the sun of righteousness shall arise with healing in its wings.

> 2 Peter 3:11 KJV (11)  ***Seeing then that all these things shall be
>   dissolved, what manner of persons ought ye to be in all holy
>   conversation and godliness,***

We must strive to enter into that rest though. There remains a rest to enter into.

We must cease from our own “works of righteousness”…the keeping and serving of the doctrines and commandments of men ( those “elements”….those “rudiments” of the world ….those commandments of men….that cause us to perish from off this earth). The "elements" burn us as we perish with the using of them under His wrath.

> Hebrews 4:9-11 KJV (9)  *There remaineth therefore a rest to the people
>   of God. (10)  For he that is entered into his rest, he also hath
>   ceased from his own works, as God did from his. (11)  **Let us labour
>   therefore to enter into that rest,** lest any man fall after the same
>   example of unbelief.*

If any man be in Christ, he is a new creation as the old things are passed away (from being under His wrath where there is death, sorrow, pain, crying).  We shall be a new creation where there is no death, sorrow, pain, crying...and this is for this earth as the Son was sent to this world so that this world might be saved.

> 2 Corinthians 5:17-20 KJV (17)  ***Therefore if any man be in Christ, he
>   is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all things are
>   become new.***

We are to be reconciled unto God.

> (18)  *And all things are of God, who hath reconciled us to himself by
>   Jesus Christ, and hath given to us the ministry of reconciliation;
>   (19)  **To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto
>   himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them;** and hath committed
>   unto us the word of reconciliation. (20)  Now then we are ambassadors
>   for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us: we pray you in
>   Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God.*

He turns man to destruction and says to “RETURN”…to be reconciled to Him...and this is through His Son Jesus the Christ.

> Psalms 90:3-11 KJV (3)  ***Thou turnest man to destruction; and sayest,
>   Return, ye children of men.*** (4)  For a thousand years in thy sight are
>   but as yesterday when it is past, and as a watch in the night. (5) 
>   Thou carriest them away as with a flood; they are as a sleep: in the
>   morning they are like grass which groweth up. (6)  In the morning it
>   flourisheth, and groweth up; in the evening it is cut down, and
>   withereth.

His wrath is revealed upon all as we perish in our mortal flesh from off this earth because of sins…

> (7)  ***For we are consumed by thine anger, and by thy wrath are we
>   troubled.***

…as He judges us for our iniquities that are set before Him in the light of His face. Our God is a consuming fire in which our flesh as grass withers away to the grave. We call it "aging" but this is the outward manifest wrath of God upon our mortal flesh for our sins.

> (8)  *T**hou hast set our iniquities before thee, our secret sins in the
>   light of thy countenance. (9)  For all our days are passed away in thy
>   wrath: we spend our years as a tale that is told.** (10)  The days of
>   our years are threescore years and ten; and if by reason of strength
>   they be fourscore years, yet is their strength labour and sorrow; for
>   it is soon cut off, and we fly away. (11)  Who knoweth the power of
>   thine anger? even according to thy fear, so is thy wrath.*

God reconciles the world unto Himself in Christ……..To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation

If we do not believe on the Son, then the wrath of God abides upon us still.

We are to hear His voice and do His will so that we may have His everlasting life in this earth.  Faith is active.  Faith without doing His righteousness is dead even though we may say “Lord, Lord”…professing ourselves as Christians.

> John 3:36 KJV (36)  ***He that believeth on the Son hath everlasting
>   life: and he that believeth not the Son shall not see life; but the
>   wrath of God abideth on him.***

The elements…the rudiments of the world…. burn us.   They are the keeping and serving of the handwritings of church dogmas that were written by the church scribes for us to keep.  They do nothing to save us but instead make sure we perish from off this earth by the serving of them.

We perish from off this earth by the using of their handwritings as many use them to judge others with (the sin)….labeling others as “evil doers” for not keeping our particular denomination’s teachings and commandments.  Death is a certainty by the using of them as we are destroyed as others were in the past.

> Colossians 2:20-22 KJV (20)  *Wherefore if ye be dead with Christ from
>   the rudiments of the world, why, as though living in the world, are ye
>   subject to ordinances, (21)  (Touch not; taste not; handle not; (22) 
>   **Which all are to perish with the using;) after the commandments and
>   doctrines of men?***

There is only One Judge….we are not acting as judges (“gods”) for God by judging others over the commandments of men that we keep.

There is only One Lawgiver….and not our church scribes (their “handwriting of dogmas).   We must not judge others according to what we affirm of within our own minds that should be done (our commandments).    We are not to judge others….labeling what or who is good and evil (as a “judge” does).

We must cease from speaking evil of others thinking that we are doing these things supposedly in His Name…in His authority .  We are not blessing God by cursing others with the same mouth and think that we are doing “wonderful works” in His authority.   By doing these things, we are then not a doer of the law of Christ to have love for one another but acting as a judge.  We act as judge, jury and executioner of others (condemning others to "hell") for not keeping the commandments of men that are not saving the flesh of anyone as is obvious from the many church cemeteries.

> James 4:11-12 KJV (11)  *Speak not evil one of another, brethren. He
>   that speaketh evil of his brother, and judgeth his brother, speaketh
>   evil of the law, and judgeth the law: **but if thou judge the law, thou
>   art not a doer of the law, but a judge. (12)  There is one lawgiver,
>   who is able to save and to destroy: who art thou that judgest another***?

We perish from off this earth as we “cast out devils” supposedly in His authority (name).  We are not “gods”….judges….for Him by casting out others…labeling them…. as “devils” because they do not follow or keep our particular denominational doctrines and commandments of men.  We perish with the using of the doctrines and commandments of men that are not saving the mortal flesh of anyone in this earth. Many are doing these things supposedly in His "name" or authority when they are only acting upon their own and not doing His righteousness.

> Matthew 7:21-23 KJV (21)  *Not every one that saith unto me, Lord,
>   Lord, shall enter into the kingdom of heaven; but he that doeth the
>   will of my Father which is in heaven. (22)  Many will say to me in
>   that day, Lord, Lord, have we not prophesied **in thy name?** **and in thy
>   name have cast out devils? and in thy name** done many wonderful works?
>   (23)  And then will I profess unto them, I never knew you: depart from
>   me, ye that work iniquity.*

MANY are being led astray by false prophets down the broad way to the destruction of their mortal bodies from  off this earth.  The false prophets falsely prophesy/ promise “peace and safety” in their churches where there is none as all are perishing from off this earth as we speak.  No mortal flesh is being saved in their company as multitudes are being led astray from the Way of righteousness….the narrow way that leads to the eternal life of Jesus in this earth.

> Matthew 7:12-15 KJV (12)  *Therefore all things whatsoever ye would
>   that men should do to you, do ye even so to them: for this is the law
>   and the prophets. (13)  **Enter ye in at the strait gate: for wide is
>   the gate, and broad is the way, that leadeth to destruction, and many
>   there be which go in thereat**: (14)  Because strait is the gate, and
>   narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life, and few there be that find
>   it. (15)  **Beware of false prophets,** which come to you in sheep's
>   clothing, but inwardly they are ravening wolves.*

Their presence among us is according to the working of Satan as they perform outward “signs” in their churches of supposed inward realities.  They fascinate by the sight of their outward signs that they are showing/performing in their churches and yet no flesh is being saved by them.

Their lying wonders are their great swelling words of emptiness that flatter us for our “wonder”…our admiration.  (Jude 1:16).   They speak these words for their own unjust gain.

Their “power” is their handwriting of church dogmas that we are supposed to keep and serve….and by doing so, we are guaranteed to perish from off this earth. They have the power of death in the preaching of them.

By keeping and serving their handwriting of church dogmas, we are destroyed from off this earth because we are still abiding under His wrath (where there is death, sorrow, crying, pain) as we have not entered into His rest (where there is no death, sorrow, pain, crying).

> 2 Thessalonians 2:9-12 KJV (9)  ***Even him, whose coming is after the
>   working of Satan with all power and signs and lying wonders***,

Those who love the Truth DO it.  They are not just hearers but also doers so that they might be saved…entering into His rest and out from under His wrath.

> (10)  ***And with all deceivableness of unrighteousness in them that
>   perish; because they received not the love of the truth, that they
>   might be saved.***

But those who are still being destroyed under His wrath (as the world is condemned already), believe that they have “peace and safety” to judge…to speak evil of others …using their handwritings as their own “law” to do so.

The false prophet is saying “peace, peace” where there is none as they are perishing...being destroyed...from off this earth in the judgment of God upon them.   And so they think that they have peace to do THE lie supposedly in His authority…and they take pleasure in it.

> (11)  ***And for this cause God shall send them strong delusion, that
>   they should believe a lie: (12)  That they all might be damned who
>   believed not the truth, but had pleasure in unrighteousness.***

“Let us eat and drink and be merry **for tomorrow we shall die**”….as they rejoice in their church activities while the sheep are perishing from off this earth while the leaders enrich themselves and say "praise the Lord for I am rich" as they receive their earthly things (what to eat, what to drink what to wear) from their congregations that are being led astray.

Death is not a friend but an enemy to be defeated only in Christ.  Death is not a blessed entrance into Heaven but a stinging realization of the sin that was within our lives in this earth because we listened to the ministers of Satan.

The wages of the sin is death….death to the mortal body.  This is a here-and-now thing as the wrath of God is revealed from Heaven now as  men perish from off this earth.

Their mortal bodies wither away (all flesh is as grass) under His wrath until they “fly away” back to Him.  The wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who by their unrighteousness suppress the truth (Romans 1:18).  This Day of the Lord is not a day to desire.

> Isaiah 22:12-14 KJV *(12)  And in that day did the Lord GOD of hosts
>   call to weeping, and to mourning, and to baldness, and to girding with
>   sackcloth: (13)  And behold joy and gladness, slaying oxen, and
>   killing sheep, eating flesh, and drinking wine: **let us eat and drink;
>   for to morrow we shall die.** (14)  And it was revealed in mine ears by
>   the LORD of hosts, **Surely this iniquity shall not be purged from you
>   till ye die,** saith the Lord GOD of hosts.*

They desire to die and go to Heaven when the life of Jesus is to be experience in the here-and-now.  They have totally missed the point of His Son being sent into this world so that this world might be saved…to have life and have it more abundantly. Whosoever believes into Him (believing is DOING) should NOT PERISH but have eternal life.  This eternal life is the life of Jesus that manifests in our mortal flesh in this world.  If we perish, then we have truly missed the point and our mortal death brings a stinging realization.

> John 3:14-18 KJV (14)  *And as Moses lifted up the serpent in the
>   wilderness, even so must the Son of man be lifted up: (15)  **That
>   whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have eternal life.**
>   (16)  **For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son,
>   that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have
>   everlasting life. (17)  For God sent not his Son into the world to
>   condemn the world; but that the world through him might be saved.** (18)
>   He that believeth on him is not condemned: but he that believeth not
>   is condemned already, because he hath not believed in the name of the
>   only begotten Son of God.*

They experience the sting of death when they die and realize that they have mortally died because of the sin that they were deluded by false prophets into doing.

Why desire the Day of the LORD…the day our our own death…for it is darkness and not light.  Death is not a friend but an enemy.

> Amos 5:18-23 KJV (18)  ***Woe unto you that desire the day of the LORD!
>   to what end is it for you? the day of the LORD is darkness, and not
>   light***.

The sting of death is the sin….and what a sting it is to realize that one’s life was wasted here by being led astray by false prophets that we listened to and followed unto our own destruction from off this earth without receiving the eternal life of Jesus in the here and now.  We have then believed in vain.

Many thought that they were doing everything right by believing and going to church and serving the handwriting of church dogmas only to realize upon their mortal death it was all wrong…very wrong.  What a sting…what a shocking realization.

> (19)  ***As if a man did flee from a lion, and a bear met him; or went
>   into the house, and leaned his hand on the wall, and a serpent bit
>   him. (20)  Shall not the day of the LORD be darkness, and not light?
>   even very dark, and no brightness in it?***

Going to their churches is not doing any good.

> (21)  *I hate, I despise your feast days, and I will not smell in your
>   solemn assemblies. (22)  Though ye offer me burnt offerings and your
>   meat offerings, I will not accept them: neither will I regard the
>   peace offerings of your fat beasts. (23)  Take thou away from me the
>   noise of thy songs; for I will not hear the melody of thy viols*.

His patience with us is our salvation though.  He is not willing that any should perish (to be destroyed from off this earth) but that all should come to repentance.

> 2 Peter 3:9-10 KJV (9)  *The Lord is not slack concerning his promise,
>   as some men count slackness; but is longsuffering to us-ward, **not
>   willing that any should perish, but that all should come to
>   repentance.***

The Day of the Lord comes unexpectedly as we all know as people perish unexpectedly a lot.   The “Day of the Lord” speaks of the day of our own death when the Lord comes to take us away from off this earth.

Death is an enemy and not a friend.

This is not a day to be rejoiced as this unexpected day is darkness when He comes to remove us.  It has a “sting” attached to it:  the realization that we have been deceived by false prophets into doing THE sin in their churches.

The wages of the sin is death….death to the mortal body that perishes from this earth under the sun of His wrath.   Death is not gain but LOSS.  We suffer loss:  the mortal body.  Death is NOT a friend but an enemy that is only defeated in Christ.

The heavens come near to us to remove us.  The heavens come near to us …not “pass away”… but pass by us for our removal from this earth.

**They come with a “great noise”…that is, a whirring sound.**

That whirring sound is the sound of the whirlwind of God ‘s final judgment that comes to remove the wicked from this earth in the day of their personal death. His wrath is then done upon us as we fly away back to God.

All of their works burn up from off this earth as they are no longer here to do anything.  They are exposed in that Day that their works were not works of righteousness as they suffered loss:  the mortal body. Let us not do what they did for their works of righteousness has proved to us not to have saved any of them that have died under His wrath. The Day (the Day of the Lord) manifests what "work" they were doing to the rest of us who are still living.

> (10)  ***But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night; in
>   the which the heavens shall pass away with a great noise, and the
>   elements shall melt with fervent heat, the earth also and the works
>   that are therein shall be burned up.***

As the whirlwind passes by, so is the wicked no more in this earth. The whirring sound is the whirlwind of God's wrath coming to remove people from this earth in the day of their personal death. His wrath is then finished upon them.

> Proverbs 10:25 KJV (25)  **As the whirlwind passeth, so is the wicked no
>   more: but the righteous is an everlasting foundation**

They suffer loss…the loss of their mortal bodies as they perish (and all of their “works” along with them) in the fire of His wrath from off this earth.  He himself (the spirit) is saved but only as by fire as the temple of God (our mortal body) is destroyed from off this earth.

> 1 Corinthians 3:12-17 KJV (12)  *Now if any man build upon this
>   foundation gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay, stubble; (13) 
>   **Every man's work shall be made manifest: for the day shall declare it,**
>   because it shall be revealed by fire; and the fire shall try every
>   man's work of what sort it is. (14)  If any man's work abide which he
>   hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward. (15)  If any man's
>   work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be
>   saved; yet so as by fire. (16)  Know ye not that ye are the temple of
>   God, and that the Spirit of God dwelleth in you?*
>
> (17)  **If any man defile the temple of God, him shall God destroy; for
>   the temple of God is holy, which temple ye are**.

He is not willing that any should perish.  We are to strive to enter into His rest:  the Day of God.

The Day of God has come when the tabernacle of God is with us as He wipes away all tears from our eyes and there shall be no more death, neither sorrow, nor crying, nor pain as the former things of death, sorrow, crying, pain experienced under His wrath that arises upon all men shall “dissolve” as we enter into His rest.    This is in this world as the holy city comes down from God out of Heaven.

> Revelation 21:2-5 KJV (2)  *And I John saw the holy city, new
>   Jerusalem, **coming down from God out of heaven,** prepared as a bride
>   adorned for her husband. (3)  And I heard a great voice out of heaven
>   saying, Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell
>   with them, and they shall be his people, and God himself shall be with
>   them, and be their God. (4)  **And God shall wipe away all tears from
>   their eyes; and there shall be no more death, neither sorrow, nor
>   crying, neither shall there be any more pain: for the former things
>   are passed away.** (5)  And he that sat upon the throne said, **Behold, I
>   make all things new.** And he said unto me, Write: for these words are
>   true and faithful.*

Again, The “Day of the Lord” speaks of the Day of Judgment when He comes to take us out of this earth via the day of our death.  We all know that this comes as a thief in the night for we see many being taken from this life unexpectedly.  We don’t know when He will come to do this.  The wages of the sin is death to the mortal body….and death is not a “friend” but an enemy.  Why wish for the Day of the Lord for what is it to us?  It is darkness and not light.  It is a day of distress as the sting of death is the sin. It is not something to be desired as many seem to do so that they can get to Heaven.

We are to strive to enter His rest…the Day of God that we are to anticipate and speed toward by being holy…. under the shadow of the Almighty and out from under the sun of His wrath that destroys our mortal flesh because of our sins.